# How to avoid possible Null Pointer deference

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, null-pointer

I have made a simple `add` method that takes two args.
Here is the code :

```
public List<myListType> add(List<myListType> myTypes, myListType myType) {
    if (myTypes == null) {
        myTypes = new ArrayList<myListType>();
    }

    int size = myTypes.size();

    if (size > 1) {

        Boolean lastStatus = myTypes.get(myTypes.size()-1).getAvailabilityStatus();

        Boolean secondLastElement = myTypes.get(myTypes.size() - 2).getAvailabilityStatus();
        if (lastStatus == null && secondLastElement == null) {
            myTypes.remove(myTypes.size()-1);
        }
        else if (lastStatus.equals(secondLastElement)) {

            myTypes.remove(myTypes.size()-1);
        }
    }

    myTypes.add(myType);

    return myTypes;
}
```

I think there is actually a possible null pointer deference in the `if` condition, especially on `lastStatus`. Do you see something I can do in order to avoid that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using java 7+, you can use `Objects.equals`, which takes care of both your conditions:

```
Boolean secondLastElement = myTypes.get(myTypes.size() - 2).getAvailabilityStatus();
if (Objects.equals(lastStatus, secondLastElement)) {
    myTypes.remove(myTypes.size()-1);
}
```

Comment: Is the method `equals` applicable for the arguments (Boolean, Boolean) ? What about Java 6 ?

Comment: In Java6, if `a` and `b` are both `null`, `a.equals(b)` throws a `NPE`. Java 7's `Objects.equals` would return `true` if both are `null`. Also, `Objects.equals` takes two `Object` arguments, so therefore it is applicable to `(Boolean, Boolean)`.